Electron transport chain
I am learning about electron transport chain . I have seen that complex 1 and 3 pumps H+ ions across the inner mitochondrial membrane . To do this it uses the electric work done to move electrons through the f-s clusters in the complexes . Nowhere it was shown that exactly how moving electrons in those cluster can do work on H+ ions to move them so can someone explain me that in details?
